# Seeking Argentina-Buenos Aires immigration and residential records for Dusan Biukovic

Tags: immigration, manifest, 1920s, yugoslavia, argentina

My grandfather Dusan (or Daniel) Biukovic (surname versions: Biucovich, Biukovich) migrated from Svinica, Yugoslavia (now Croatia) in 1926 and probably died in Buenos Aires, Argentina in 1977. How to find passenger, immigration, residential or other records? Last address street name was Av. Olivera, Buenos Aires. Contact person was: Anna Maria Aurora Garcia Dell Vale.

Comment: Hello and welcome. I've removed your contact details as those should be in your profile, not the question. Might the 'contact person' still be alive? -- if so their name will need to be removed to maintain their privacy.

Answer (score 1):

You have not provided any sources for Dusan's emigration in 1926, or his possible death in 1977, or a date for that last known street address, or birth/baptism details for him, but when I searched Ancestry.com for the exact name that you provided this [Find A Grave entry](https://www.findagrave.com/memorial/114074907) showed up:

```
Dusan Biukovic
BIRTH   1904
Croatia
DEATH   1942 (aged 37–38)
Croatia
BURIAL  
Jasenovac Concentration Camp
Jasenovac, Opcina Jasenovac, Sisacko-Moslavacka, Croatia
MEMORIAL ID 114074907
```

Answer (score 0):

If this is the family required by you as it would appear to be. This would provide a new approach to tracing and extending the coverage of the person and also family required by you via the American records on the family, which are likely to be easier to trace and work with than the South American records from which to move forward in this instance.

```
Household   Role    Sex Age Birthplace
Dusan Bukurovich    Head    Male    56  Yugoslavia
Solveta Bukurovich  Wife    Female  51  Yugoslavia
Saveta Boldlovich   Niece   Female  13  Indiana

Last Place of Residence:    Chicago, Cook, Illinois
```

United states Census 1940

Dusan Bukurovich
United States World War II Draft Registration Cards, 1942
Name:   Dusan Bukurovich
Event Type: Draft Registration
Event Date: 1942
Event Place:    Chicago, Cook, Illinois, United States
Residence Place:    Chicago, Cook, Illinois
Gender: Male
Employer:   Dusan/Bukurovich
Birth Date: 15 May 1883